# Reference Request: Degree of a holomorphic vector bundle over a compact Riemann Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

I need to learn about holomorphic vector bundles over a compact Riemann Surface, but I'm not finding a good bibliography about that.

Specifically, now I'm trying to understand the degree classification. Anyone knows where I could find more about this?

Comment: Rick Miranda algebraic curves and Riemann Surfaces